# Evaluating polynomial at rational point

Tags: functions, polynomials, arithmetic

When evaluating a polynomial at a rational number, is there an identity which would allow to separately evaluate it at the numerator and denominator? More formally, is there a rule to expand $f(a/b)$ into separate evaluations of some kind at $f(a)$ and $f(b)$?

It is possible to evaluate $f(a)$ with Horner's method and $f(1/b)$ equals to $rev(f)(b)/b^{degree(f)}$ (where $rev$ reverses the order of coefficients). What I'm struggling with is how to rewrite $f(a/b)$?

For example for exponentiation, $x^{a-b}$ can be rewritten as $x^a/x^b$. Is there something similar for polynomial evaluation?

Comment: don't you mean $x^{a-b} = \frac{x^a}{x^b}$?

Comment: $x^{a/b} \neq x^{a} /x^b = x^{a-b} $ for positive $x$, with the inequality holding for almost all choices of $a, b$.

Comment: @Chinny84 Sorry, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is no, this is not possible for a general polynomial, and there's no real reason that it should be possible.